# Pass "selected" <option> as page loads

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-select

I've got a problem. I'm trying to show restaurant's revenue graph of `selected` year and as a default. I want it to be showing this year's graph, in this case 2020. I used `selected` on this year's date, but the problem is that I have `onchange`. It only shows graph if I change something, reselect. Is there a good way to use first option as default?

```php
<select id="yearPick" name="yearPick" onchange="load_new_content()">
  <option value="year" disabled>year</option>
  <option value="<?php echo date("Y"); ?>" selected><?php echo date("Y"); ?></option>
  <?php for ($i = date("Y") - 1; $i >= 1980; $i--) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Just call `load_new_content()` once the document is ready. Usually, if not set otherwise, the selected value of a select is the value of its first option.

Comment: That helped, it was really simple tho, thank you!